# Alpine.js with Laravel: preselect dynamic option in select after page reload

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

I'm kinda new to Alpine.js and I have 3 selects in my blade view: make, model, engine. Options on model and engine are dynamic and being populated once the previous select has been changed (just to be able to select a vehicle with corresponding configuration):

```
<div class="md:col-span-5" x-data="{
        selectedMake: '',
        selectedModel: '',
        models: [],
        engines: [],
        isLoading: false,
        makeDisabled: false,
        engineDisabled: false,
        showAlert: false,
        isFormValid: false,
        fetchModels() {
            fetchModels(this.selectedMake, this.models, this.isLoading, this.makeDisabled);
        },
        fetchEngines() {
            fetchEngines(this.selectedModel, this.engines, this.isEngineLoading, this.engineDisabled)
        },
        resetEnginesSelector() {
            this.selectedModel = '';
            this.engines = [];
            this.engineDisabled = true;
        },
        checkFormValidity() {
            this.isFormValid = this.selectedMake !== '' && this.selectedModel !== '';
        },
    }"
    x-init="$watch('selectedMake', () => { resetEnginesSelector(); checkFormValidity() }); $watch('selectedModel', () => checkFormValidity())"
>
    <x-forms.select label="Make"
        x-model="selectedMake"
        @change="fetchModels"
        x-bind:disabled="isLoading || makeDisabled"
        id="make"
        name="make"
        :options="$makes"
        required />

    <select name="model"
        id="model"
        @change="fetchEngines"
        x-model="selectedModel"
        required
        x-bind:disabled="Object.keys(models).length === 0 || isLoading"
        class="form-control"
    >
        <option value="" selected>Please select</option>
        <template x-for="model in models" :key="model.id">
            <option x-bind:value="model.id" x-text="model.name"></option>
        </template>
    </select>

    <select name="engine"
        id="engine"
        required
        x-bind:disabled="Object.keys(engines).length === 0 || isLoading"
        class="form-control"
    >
        <option value="" selected>Please select</option>
        <template x-for="engine in engines" :key="engine.id">
            <option x-bind:value="engine.id" x-text="engine.name"></option>
        </template>
    </select>
</div>
```

And in my `<script>` tag, there is the following:

```
function fetchEngines(
    selectedModel,
    engines,
    isLoading,
    engineDisabled
) {
    engineDisabled = true;
    isLoading = true;

    fetch(router.fetchEngines, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-Token': token,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            model: selectedModel
        })
    })
    .then(r => {
        if (!r.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok')
        }

        return r.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        engines.splice(0, engines.length, ...data);
        engineDisabled = false;
    })
    .finally(() => {
        isLoading = false;
    })
}

function fetchModels(
    selectedMake,
    models,
    isLoading,
    makeDisabled
) {
    makeDisabled = true;
    isLoading = true;

    fetch(router.fetchModels, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-Token': token,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            make: selectedMake
        })
    })
        .then(r => {
            if (!r.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok')
            }

            return r.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            models.splice(0, models.length, ...data);
            makeDisabled = false;
        })
        .finally(() => {
            isLoading = false;
        })
    }
```

So, what I am trying to achieve is: **when the backend validation fails or any other backend exception is being thrown, I want to return back to the form and these 3 selects to be pre-populated and pre-checked with old values**.

For this reason in my Laravel Controller, I am returning a redirect response: `return back()->withInput()`.

I have tried to set the `selectedMake` and `selectedEngine`, by including old values in the x-data part:

```
selectedMake: '{{ old('make') }}',
selectedModel: '{{ old('model') }}',
selectedEngine: '{{ old('engine') }}',
....
```

But that didn't work, since only the Make select has been selected, but Model and Engine selects were not pre-populated with options.

As ChatGPT suggested, I even created a separate function:

```
if (oldMake && oldModel) {
    fetchModels(oldMake);
    fetchEngines(oldModel);
}
```

and in `x-init` of the first DIV I added the `fetchModels(selectedMake); fetchEngines(selectedModel)` part. That didn't work as well, since again - only Make select has been selected, but Model and Engine selects were not, since these are empty at that moment.

How can I achieve the desired behavior, so that all 3 selects are prefilled and preselected with old values?

**P.S.** As you can see, I have a Make select already pre-populated from backend, since Make list is static and for this reason, I created a blade component. For other 2 selects I used the regular HTML select with Alpine attributes.

**P.P.S.:** An idea came to me while writing this question: on my Backend, I could already pre-fetch the model and engines list and maybe send these 2 lists as a session variable: `return back()->with(['models' => ...])->withInput();` and put the list somewhere in JS and then somehow preselect without AJAX request

### **Update 1**

I have came up with a somehow almost working solution:

```
<div x-data="{
    selectedMake: '{{ old('make') }}',
    selectedModel: '{{ old('model') }}',
    selectedEngine: '{{ old('engine') }}',
    ... // other code, unchanged
}">
    <select name="model" id="model" @change="fetchEngines" 
        x-init="if (selectedModel !== '') (this.selectedMake, this.models, this.isLoading, this.makeDisabled)"
        x-model="selectedModel"
        required
        x-bind:disabled="Object.keys(models).length === 0 || isLoading"
        class="form-control"
    >
        <option value="" selected>Please select</option>
        <template x-for="model in models" :key="model.id">
            <option :value="model.id" :selected="model.id == this.selectedModel" x-text="model.name"></option>
        </template>
    </select>
```

In this case, the `models` select is being pre-populated, but **not yet pre-selected**. What am I missing? I have tried `x-bind:selected` and `:selected` on the `option` tag, but nothing seems to work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And so, here is the solution of couple of hours trying to understand. It means that I misunderstood what is `this` in context. So instead of the `:selected="model.id == this.selectedModel"` I used `:selected="model.id == selectedModel"`.

This is the complete working solution:

```
<div class="md:col-span-5" x-data="{
    selectedMake: '{{ old('make') }}',
    selectedModel: '{{ old('model') }}',
    selectedEngine: '{{ old('engine') }}',
    // other code unchanged
>
    <select name="model"
        id="model"
        @change="fetchEngines"
        x-init="if (selectedModel !== '') fetchModels(this.selectedMake, this.models, this.isLoading, this.makeDisabled)"
        x-model="selectedModel"
        required
        x-bind:disabled="Object.keys(models).length === 0 || isLoading"
        class="form-control"
    >
        <option value="" selected>Please select</option>
        <template x-for="model in models" :key="model.id">
            <option :value="model.id" :selected="model.id == selectedModel" x-text="model.name"></option>
        </template>
    </select>
</div>
```